# How to write integer arrays into pipe and how to read the first from it?

Tags: c, linux, fork

Source Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>


int main(){
    int fd1[2];
    int sample[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int input[] ={5 , 6, 7,8};
    pid_t p;

    if (pipe(fd1)==-1)return 1;
    if (pipe(fd2)==-1) return 1;

    write(fd1[1], input, sizeof(input)+1);
    write(fd1[1], sample, sizeof(sample)+1);
    close(fd1[1]);
    char concat[100];
    read(fd1[0],concat,100);
    int i=0;
    for(i;i<sizeof(concat);i++){
            printf("%i ",concat[i]);

}
        printf("\n");

}
```

I want to write arrays in on pipe, and after that i want to read out the first array only, not the whole pipe or not like in the code:

```
read(fd1[0],concat,100);
```

Is this possible? If it's not I will use structs.

Comment: Please format your code so that it's legible.

Comment: You need to write the whole array into the pipe. But why do you want to use a pipe for this? Please read this: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: you seem to have managed to write some code that'll write/read one int? repeating it for an array is just an extension of that using a loop.

Comment: The task is: Write a c code using fork() and Divide and conquer algorithm, and sort the array in a ascending order  what is in input.dat and put the sorted array to output.dat.

Comment: @zarnilord you should make this clear in the question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating two array of int via pipe.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>


int main()
{
    int fd1[2];
    int fd2[2];

    int sample[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int input[] ={5 , 6, 7,8};
    pid_t p;

    if (pipe(fd1)==-1)return 1;
    if (pipe(fd2)==-1) return 1;

    p = fork();

    if (p < 0) return 1;

    // Parent process
    else if (p > 0)
    {
        int concat[100];
        close(fd1[0]);
        write(fd1[1], input, sizeof(input)+1);
        close(fd1[1]);

        wait(NULL);

        close(fd2[1]);
        read(fd2[0], concat, 100);

        printf(" %i", concat[0]);
        printf(" %i", concat[1]);
        printf(" %i", concat[2]);
        printf(" %i", concat[3]);

        close(fd2[0]);
    }

    // child process
    else
    {
        close(fd1[1]);
        char concat[100];
        read(fd1[0], concat, 100);
        int k = sizeof(concat);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<sizeof(sample); i++)
            concat[k++] = sample[i];

        concat[k] = '\0';

        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd2[0]);

        write(fd2[1], concat, sizeof(concat)+1);
        close(fd2[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was my fault, I was inaccurate last time, I modified the question now. Can u help me solve this problem?